# Conditional changes to the existence of sub arrays inside a multi dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a Master PHP array at the bottom of my question. It all works as it should and encodes to json perfectly. My problem is confined to the "content" object shown in the array.

The 'content' object should contain up to ten sub-arrays ($newSubArray0-9)each sub-array being populated with image data according to this simple loop below (the data is all available from a prior database query - so no issues there).

```
//get data for the 'content' object sub arrays....
for( $i = 0; $i<9; $i++ ) {
$newSubArray.$i = 
[
'url' => $uploadspath.$media_url.$i,//main image
"type" =>$type.$i,//media type
"caption"=>$caption.$i
];
}
```

Now...in the master array below I simply need to be able to exclude or delete any of the $newSubArray (0-9) instances IF its corresponding media-condition yields an empty media result ie (!media_url.$i) or ($media_url.$i="").

I have tried...

```
If (media-conditon) 
 ...{$newSubArray.$i=UNSET($newSubArray.$i);}
 ...{$newSubArray.$i=array_filter($newSubArray.$i);}
 ...{$newSubArray.$i=array_values($newSubArray.$i);}
```

All of these attempts affect the subarray elements I am trying to delete entirely (based on the condition) BUT leave a trace of the subarray itself eg 'none'. That trace causes the subsequent data validation to fail. The vailidation is being done by a third party API to which the json data is sent--so I cannot change the validation. I need there to be absolutely NO record of any subarray for which there is no associated $media_url value.

Here is a portion of the Master Array with the sub array elements that I need to conditionally include or exclude depending on the availability of associated images. It all works fine ...just need to solve the problem above.

```
$data = json_encode
(
 array
    (

            "location" =>array  
            (
                "property_number_or_name" => $house_name_number,
                "street_name" => $propaddress1,
                "locality" => $propaddress2,
                "town_or_city" => $town,
                "postal_code" => $postcode,
                "country_code" => "GB",
                "coordinates"=>array
                                    (

                                        "latitude"=>(float)$latitude,
                                        "longitude"=>(float)$longitude

                                    )
            ),

            "pricing" =>array  
            (
            "rent_frequency" => $rent_frequency,
            "currency_code" => "GBP",
            "price" => (int)$price,
            "transaction_type" => "rent"
            ),


            "detailed_description" =>array  
                                        (
                                        array
                                            (
                                            "text" => $description
                                            )
                                        ),

            "content" => array
                        (
                            $newSubArray0,//remove this sub array completely if no media_url0 
                            $newSubArray1,//remove this sub array completely if no media_url1 
                            $newSubArray2,//remove this sub array completely if no media_url2 
                            $newSubArray3,//remove this sub array completely if no media_url3 
                            $newSubArray4,//remove this sub array completely if no media_url4 
                            $newSubArray5,//remove this sub array completely if no media_url5 
                            $newSubArray6,//remove this sub array completely if no media_url6 
                            $newSubArray7,//remove this sub array completely if no media_url7 
                            $newSubArray8,//remove this sub array completely if no media_url8 
                            $newSubArray9 //remove this sub array completely        if no media_url9                            
                        ),  

            "google_street_view"=>array
                            (
                            "heading"=>(float)$pov_heading,
                            "pitch"=> (float)$pov_pitch,
                            "coordinates"=> array                               
                                        (
                                        "latitude"=>(float)$pov_latitude,
                                        "longitude"=>(float)$pov_longitude
                                        )
                            ),


            "display_address"=> $display_address,
            "summary_description"=> $summary

,JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

Answer (score 0):

You likely want [`unset`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) but to not store the result of the call in the same place.

Yours:

```
If (media-conditon) 
    ...{$newSubArray.$i=UNSET($newSubArray.$i);}
```

Update:

```
If (media-conditon) 
    ...{UNSET($newSubArray.$i);}
```

You could also do this more efficiently by validating your media condition before you set the element in the content data.

Comment: Hi Kevin. Thank you for this. I am pretty confused about why unset does not work. Could you  give me a little bit of an explanation of your new suggestion please. [Am happy to set up the content array first by the way]. Just trying to keep this as simple as possible as there are a whole bunch of instances of this code.

Comment: If there are a bunch of instances of the code, you should look towards abstracting it. To help further with why unset isn't working for you, we'll need more of your real code instead of pseudo-code as in your question.

Comment: IF ($X==2){UNSET($newSubArray7);}

Comment: What i get back is the folowing message ...    { "message" : "None is not of type 'object'", "path" : "#/content/7" }

Comment: I had actually tried that fix earlier. Same problem. Its still seeing the trace 'none'

Comment: Kevin--this is real code. It works. It is live. Its an abstract of real code. What is it you are not seeing that you need to see?

Comment: Can you please post a *full* copy of one of your instances of this code? Seeing the whole structure of the code involved can help us a lot here. This could be as simple as changing your `UNSET($newSubArray7);` to `UNSET($data['content'][$i]);`, but we won't be able to know for sure without the full code.

Comment: Thank you Kevin. I have solved the problem by creating the sub array separately and adding the conditional logic outside of the array. So rather than using unset i simply dont include the array or sub elements in the first place. Which is exactly as you suggested in your earlier post on Nov 30th!  You were spot on with that advice--so much easier, Again thank you.